# Magento custom option

Tags: magento

I am working with magento 1.8.1 and I have problems in the resolution of personalized options for customized products.

My product calculates the price based on several options. The first is for quantity of items ordered and type of color, size ... well this is calculated.

But the problem is that if you want to customize an article, an option is available to select, but this has a fixed precione, and this should change with respect to the number of items ordered.

**example**: 
5 jerseys € 25 + € 5 Customization

10 jerseys € 45 + € 5 Customization

and this is the problem.